# How to achieve backwards compatibility with my .NET plugin architecture

Tags: .net, deployment, plugins, backwards-compatibility

**Background:**
I am developing an ASP.NET application with a server side plug in architecture. 
I define a set of interfaces in a pluginInterfaces .NET assembly.

Third party developers can develop a plugin assembly against these interfaces, place their assembly in a plugin folder, and it will be dynamically loaded to offer new functionality.

The plugins will reference the plugin interfaces assembly.

**Problem:**
In the future I may update my pluginInterfaces assembly with new functionality, but it will 
remain 100% backward compatible (i.e. interfaces will not changed). However the pluginInterfaces assembly will have a new assembly version number.

I want (third party) plugin assemblies to just continue to work. 
But they will no longer find the pluginInterfaces assembly that they were built against.
The pluginInterfaces assembly will have a strong name, and hence the plugins will look for 
the version with exact matching assembly version.

**Question:**
What is the best way to achieve this?
Is this what 'Publisher Policy' is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [binding redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/eftw1fys(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I think we will need to do this in the future - that is put our shared assemblies in the GAC and when we update them also install a policy dll into the GAC, to redirect references to old versions to the new version.